# Changing the collection of Itemsource Dynamically in HierarchialDataTemplate of TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, itemsource

TreeView has to be populated recursively with different collection.

I was able to populate perfectly when i had only one type of collection from second level. But now I have a requirement to handle two different collection after second level.

I tried to create Observable Collection of ViewModelBase Class which is actually extended to all other ViewModel class, thinking that I can any type of ViewModel instance to Observable Collection. But this will work when i don't have to work with two different collection at a time.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewModelBase}" ItemsSource="{Binding SecondViewModelCollection}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Image Source="../resources/New_Package.png" Width="15" Height="15"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Loaded="Project_Loaded"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewModelBase}" ItemsSource="{Binding ThirdViewModelCollection}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Image Source="../resources/New_Package.png" Width="15" Height="15"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewModelBase}" ItemsSource="{Binding FourthViewModelBaseCollection}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Source="../resources/New_Package.png" Width="15" Height="15"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"  MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseUp" 
                                                       Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" Focusable="True"/>
                                            <TextBox LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" Visibility="Collapsed" MouseEnter="TextBox_MouseEnter"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewModelBase}" ItemsSource="{Binding FeatureViewModelCollection}">
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Image Source="../resources/file.png" Width="15" Height="15"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewModelBase}" ItemsSource="{Binding Usecaselist}">
                                                        <StackPanel>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"  MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseUp" 
                                                                       Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" Focusable="True" />

                                                            <TextBox LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" Visibility="Collapsed" MouseEnter="TextBox_MouseEnter"/>

                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewModelBase}">
                                                                <StackPanel >
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseUp"  
                                                                               Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded"  Focusable="True" />

                                                                    <TextBox 
                                                                             LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                                             MouseEnter="TextBox_MouseEnter" >
                                                                    </TextBox>
                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
```

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

```
> Level 1
      > Level 2.1 (Diff class with diff. collection)
         > Level 3.1 (Diff from other 3.1)
           > Level 4.1
           > Level 4.2
         > Level 3.2 (Diff from other 3.2)
         > Level 3.3 (Diff from other 3.3)
      > Level 2.2 (Diff class with diff. collection)
         > Level 3.1 (Diff from other 3.1)
         > Level 3.2 (Diff from other 3.2)
      > Level 2.3 (Diff class with diff. collection)
         > Level 3.1 (Diff from other 3.1)
         > Level 3.2 (Diff from other 3.2)
```

Now the Objects of ThirdViewModelCollection is of two type, not just the datatype/ object is different, but the collection within them will be different from here.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703365/how-to-bind-two-different-collection-at-one-treeview-branch/56705158#56705158

Answer (score 1):

It is a requirement that all data types must extend a common base type (e.g. `ViewModelBase`). Then you can (and should) mix the types contained in a collection of that common base type (e.g. `ObservableCollection<ViewModeBase>`) so that each node has exactly one collection holding the child items which extend the common tree's base type.
Then use a `DataTemplateSelector` to return the appropriate `DataTemplate` for a node type.

This way the TreeView is generated dynamically no matter the width or height as long there exists a `DataTemplate` for each possible node type.

**The dynamic `TreeView`**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource DataTemplateSelector}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <local:DataTemplateSelector x:Key="DataTemplateSelector" />

<!-- The DataTemplates for each node type -->   
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FirstDataTemplate"
                              DataType="FirstViewModel"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SecondDataTemplate"
                              DataType="SecondViewModel"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ThirdDataTemplate"
                              DataType="ThirdViewModel"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="IndFeatureDataTemplate"
                              DataType="IndFeatureViewModel"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="IndUsecaseDataTemplate"
                  DataType="IndUsecaseViewModel">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**The DataTemplateSelector for the TreeView**

```
class DataTemplateSelector : System.Windows.Controls.DataTemplateSelector
{
  public override DataTemplate
    SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

     return item is FirstViewModel 
       ? element.FindResource("FirstDataTemplate") as DataTemplate 
       : item is SecondViewModel 
         ? element.FindResource("SecondDataTemplate") as DataTemplate
         : item is ThirdViewModel 
           ? element.FindResource("ThirdDataTemplate") as DataTemplate
           : item is IndFeatureViewModel
             ? element.FindResource("IndFeatureDataTemplate") as DataTemplate
             : element.FindResource("IndUsecaseDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
  }
}
```

**The common base type**

```
public abstract class ViewModelbase
{
  public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ChildItems { get;set; }   
  public string Name { get;set; }    
}
```

**Extended type**

```
public class FirstViewModel : ViewModelbase
{
  public FirstViewModel() 
  {
    // Create a collection with mixed types all derived from ViewModellBase
    this.ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<ViewModeLBase>() 
    { 
      new SecondViewModel(), 
      new ThirdViewModel(),
      new IndUsecaseViewModel()
    };
  }

  public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ChildItems { get;set; }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this answer it has shown how to tackle the problem of different datatype and i have adopted the same in my project. But my issue is with classes with different collection and ViewModelBase is not abstract class in mine as it is used to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I have updated the question. Pls let me know if i am missing something.